# Wizz Air website says "no flight" but I have already bought a ticket

Tags: tickets, cancellations, wizz-air

On November 2016 I bought a Wizz Air ticket, paying by credit card. The flight is in June 2017. Recently my friends, also interested in travelling to the same place as me, were checking flights and noticed that on the day and route of my ticket Wizz Air says there is no flight. It's like this for at least a week. I have received no notification about flight cancellation or any other message from Wizz Air.

Should I worry that I no longer have a flight, or is this just Wizz Air's poor way of showing that the flight is sold out and no longer available for new passengers?

Also, is there a way of contacting them which doesn't involve calling the premium rate number of their call center (an email address would be perfect)?

Comment: Can you look up your own booking?

Comment: Try Twitter or social networks?

Comment: I have flight number, flight confirmation code etc - all is in the email I got straight after my booking. But I cannot find any email contact on Wizz Air website or any other way of asking them what's happening, only the call center which is quite expensive so I'd prefer to avoid it. Will try asking on their facebook fanpage, thanks.

Comment: easyjet does the same when sold out

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you go to https://wizzair.com/ you will see this in the upper right corner:

[image]

click on "check-in & bookings" and see what your flight details are. Surely it will show if the flight has been cancelled. There does not seem to be any other way the [cancellation page](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/cancellation-information#/) only shows recent ones, not future ones.

Also note the official way of notifying you about cancellation is the telephone, here's the [General Conditions of Carriage for Passengers and Baggage](https://wizzair.com/static/docs/default-source/downloadable-documents/20160226_gcc_en4ac6bb88d1af6a18ba03ff00007faa96-sfvrsn-79_c4dc38a49078a30e894625a8305e5e3c.pdf):

> 15.3.3. We are not liable for any indemnification or compensation if We could not notify You in advance
>   of the cancellation because You were not reachable on the telephone numbers provided in Your
>   reservation.

Finally, to answer your question: if you check the United Arab Emirates number on the [contact page](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us#/)  you will find +3616777507 marked "international" rate simply, now this is an ordinary Hungarian landline number. Also you can find +3616777104 as the "International number for HU, RO etc", another Hungarian landline. +36 is Hungary, 1 is Budapest.

Comment: thanks, checked and it turns out my flight was moved to another day, when I went to link they shown me there I got standard phone number only for people whose flight was altered, will call there in the evening

Comment: Perhaps share that number for others in the future.