# With Wizzair, can I downgrade registered bag to large cabin bag?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage, wizz-air

I have a booking with a >25kg bag (to be checked in) paid for. The longer I think about it the more it looks like I could do with just a large cabin bag, slightly larger than typical handheld luggage. I have not yet checked in for the flight.

Can I somewhere switch one type of luggage to another? Upgrade is certainly possible and costs extra, but is downgrade allowed?

Comment: [Contact](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/85890/4188) Wizz Air. I suspect you would need to, anyways, to do this change.

Comment: I kind of hoped this can be done during internet check-in. I'd prefer to avoid being social if possible ;)

Comment: Does Wizzair offer an option to take a larger cabin bag for an extra fee? If so, is the fee less than the money you paid for a heavy checked in bag?

Comment: That's exactly the case, Patricia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to downgrade your luggage.

Source: I tweeted Wizzair, [their response](https://twitter.com/wizzair/status/844487562882355201) was:

> there is no possibility to downgrade your baggage. For more information, please, visit:
>   [Wizzair: Baggage](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/travel-information/baggage#/)