# Can I get my 10kg checked in baggage into cabin without WIZZ Priority

Tags: wizz-air

My mom paid for 10kg checked in baggage instead of Wizz Priority. She’ll have a small suitcase which fits into overhead compartment. Can she take her luggage with her?

Comment: Don't assume that cabin baggage fees are cheaper than hold baggage, you may have to pay extra even if the change is allowed (there's often more demand for cabin than hold). [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89983/with-wizzair-can-i-downgrade-registered-bag-to-large-cabin-bag?rq=1) is from 2017 so may not still be accurate but says you can't change.

Answer (score 3):

No. [Wizzair writes](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/wizz-services/wizz-priority)

> Only WIZZ Priority passengers are entitled to bring an extra trolley
> bag of maximum size 55 x 40 x 23 cm in addition to the free carry on
> bag (max. 40 x 30 x 20 cm) into the cabin.